# exec ./develop.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker can't find file `develop.sh` even though it's in the root directory

my `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
FROM node:16.13.0

WORKDIR /app/medusa

COPY package.json .
COPY develop.sh .
COPY yarn.* .

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y python

RUN npm install -g npm@latest

RUN npm install -g @medusajs/medusa-cli@latest

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["./develop.sh"]
```

[image]

---

Edit: I am trying to run an open source project called [medusa](https://medusajs.com/), you can find the code [here](https://github.com/medusajs/medusa-starter-default), I haven't changed any thing except node version in `Dockerfile`

Comment: just try with ENTRYPOINT [". ./develop.sh"]

Comment: I get the same error @Raushan Kumar

Comment: What are the contents of that directory, within the container? If you run the command `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/ls test -l`, what does it output? What are the contents of `develop.sh`?

Comment: okay please follow @NickODell comment

Comment: I edited the post to add more details @Nick ODell

Comment: Did you try `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/medusa/develop.sh"]` ?

Comment: You can get the error from more things than the file itself not being found; you can also get it if the interpreter for that file is not found (so if it's a _bash_ script starting with `#!/bin/bash` but you only have `/bin/sh` installed, f/e); or if a shared library used by that interpreter isn't available.

Comment: Also, `/app/medusa` is not the root directory.

Comment: `["/bin/sh", "./develop.sh"]` will force `sh` (which is more likely to be available) instead of whatever's listed in the shebang; but if it has a bash shebang, that means it's written for bash, so you really should run it with the shell its authors built it for and tested it against, even if you need to do extra work to install that shell in the container.

Comment: (btw, the fact that `.sh` files often use non-`sh` interpreters is part of why [commandname extensions (are) considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggestion: changing the entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "./develop.sh"]` solved the issue